# Rails: How to use same partial file for one to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For the normal situation. Different views can use the same partial like this

```
<h1>New zone</h1>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zones: @zones} %>

<h1>Editing zone</h1>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zones: @zones} %>

<% zones.each do |zone| %>
 <%= zone.location%>
<% end %>
```

But my situation is a bit different, the origin code like this

> one belongs_to two
>  @one = One.all

**one.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "one",locals:{one: @one} %>
```

**_one.html.erb**

```
<% one.each do |n|%>
  <%= n.location%>
<% end %>
```

> two has_many one 
> @two = Two.all

***two.html.erb***

```
<%= render partial: "two", @two %>
```

***_two.html.erb***

```
<% @two.each do |one|%>
  <% one.each do |n|%>
    <%= n.location %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

For this situation, how can I code render for two.html.erb if I want one.html.erb and two.html.erb use the same partial _one.html.erb ?
this one is definitely incorrect, but how to correct this?
**two.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: "one/one", locals: {one: @two} %>
```

**========================update============================**
I think the basic of question is whether we can use the same partial for an object and at the same time for a collection.

Comment: @Thanh Not working, undefined method `each' for ...

Comment: just call the partial inside the each block

`<% @two.each do |one|%>
  <%= render 'one/one', one: one %>
<% end %>`

Comment: @jvnill I hope just render once

Comment: ah of course. try something like `render partial: 'one/one', collection: @two, as: :one`